# Is it possible to find an explicit definition of the "universal" (co)tangent bundle?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, moduli-spaces, vector-bundles, gromov-witten-theory

Let $H_{0,1}(\mathbb{P}^2, d)$ be the space of holomorphic degree $d$ 
maps (that are not multiply covered) from $\mathbb{P}^1$ to $\mathbb{P}^2$ with one marked point 
$y \in \mathbb{P^1} $ $\textit{without}$ any equivalence 
relation imposed. Hence, there is a well defined projection map 
$$ \pi_1:H_{0,1}(\mathbb{P}^2, d) \longrightarrow \mathbb{P}^1 \qquad 
\pi_1(u,y):= y.  $$
Let us define the line bundle 
$J := \pi_1^* T\mathbb{P}^1 \longrightarrow H_{0,1}(\mathbb{P}^2, d)$. 
In words, the fiber at each point $(u,y)$ is the tangent space of 
$\mathbb{P}^1$ at $y$. Now let us define 
$$M_{0,1}(\mathbb{P}^2, d) := H_{0,1}(\mathbb{P}^2, d)/PSL(2, C) $$
Where $PSL(2, C)$ is the automorphism group of $\mathbb{P}^1$. The 
action of this group lifts to an action on the bundle $J$ and hence 
there is an induced bundle $L\rightarrow M_{0,1}(\mathbb{P}^2, d)$. 
Also note the following fact: the section of the bundle 
$J^* \otimes \mathrm{ev}^*T\mathbb{P}^2\longrightarrow H_{0,1}(\mathbb{P}^2, d)$ given by 
$$ (u,y) \longrightarrow du|_y $$ 
descends to a section of $L^* \otimes \mathrm{ev}^*T\mathbb{P}^2 \rightarrow M_{0,1}(\mathbb{P}^2, d)$. 
Here $\mathrm{ev}$ is the evaluation at the marked point $y$. 
In words, "taking deriviatve of the curve at the marked point" 
is a  well defined notion after passing to the quotient.

$\textbf{Question:}$ How does one extend the bundle $L$ to 
the compactification $\overline{M}_{0,1}(\mathbb{P}^2, d)$ so that 
the section I defined can be extended in the "obvious way", i.e. 
"taking derivative at the marked point $y$"? As a working definition of 
$\overline{M}_{0,1}(\mathbb{P}^2, d)$, I am taking it to be the topological 
space as defined via Gromov Convergence as defined in the book 
"J-Holomorphic curves and Symplectic Topology" by McDuff and Salamon.

$\textbf{Remark:}$ I believe the line bundle I am looking for is called the 
universal (co)tangent bundle, but I am not sure of this. And I am looking for 
an explicit definition along the lines I have asked.